# Attribute "default-dependency-check" is not allowed to appear in element 'beans'

Tags: spring

I'm getting strange error here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

</beans>
```

I removed every bean and I still have error:

```
Attribute "default-dependency-check" is not allowed to appear in element 'beans'
```

**EDIT**

The problem is with DOCTYPE, when I remove it it's ok, but why ?

Comment: Are you sure that Spring is picking up the XML file you posted in your question, or is it really picking up another XML file that has a `<default-dependency-check>` element? Search through your project for `default-dependency-check` to find a possible other XML file.

Comment: I eddited question

Comment: its 2016, use java config

Comment: You don't need the DOCTYPE, since your `beans` element already has references to XSDs - which means these XSDs will be used to validate the xml (you don't need the DTD to validate it again). So, just remove the DOCTYPE line.

Comment: Thank you, please add it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency-check attribute is deprecated in spring 3.0. You can use constructor injection instead of setter injection to ensure the right properties are set or else create setter method with @Required annotation where ever you required dependency check in your class

Ex: to make name dependency mandatory in your Person class

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required;

```
public class Person{
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @Required
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: and add below line in your spring configuration file
     <bean    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.
                RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
     </bean>