# Attribute 'default-dependency-check' is not allowed to appear in element 'beans'. - applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring

I searched the stackoverflow, fond a similar post here:
[Attribute "default-dependency-check" is not allowed to appear in element 'beans'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541933/attribute-default-dependency-check-is-not-allowed-to-appear-in-element-beans)

But I do not get a well-answer there.

My applicationContext.xml content is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

The issue is below:

> Attribute "default-dependency-check" is not allowed to appear in element 'beans'

I remove this line it will be ok:

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
```

---

**Edit**

I searched the project, did not find `default-dependency-check`